# How can I add a new line in Ruby 2.7+ IRB multiline edit mode?

Tags: ruby, read-eval-print-loop, irb

Ruby 2.7 introduced an update to `IRB` that allows multiline editing. How can I add a new line into a multiline method to inject code between two previous statements?

E.g.

```rb
2.7.1 :019 > while session = server.accept
2.7.1 :020 >   session.puts "Hello World! The time is #{Time.now}"
2.7.1 :021 >   session.close
2.7.1 :022 > end
```

How do I add a new line before line 21's `session.close` so I can do something like `session.puts "closing connection"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On OS X hold option and press return on the line you'd like to put a new line after.

E.g.

```rb
2.7.1 :019 > while session = server.accept
2.7.1 :020 >   session.puts "Hello World! The time is #{Time.now}" # cursor here
2.7.1 :021 >   session.close
2.7.1 :022 > end
```

press <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>

Voilà

```rb
2.7.1 :019 > while session = server.accept
2.7.1 :020 >   session.puts "Hello World! The time is #{Time.now}"
2.7.1 :021 >   
2.7.1 :022 >   session.close
2.7.1 :023 > end
```

Comment: My gut says the key combination for Linux / Windows will be similar with meta or alt + return.

Comment: Gotcha. This was done on Mojave w/ bash. Is there a meta key used more than `option` in zsh?

Answer (score 2):

#### What did not work for me

My setup is with MacOS Monterey. The proposed solution ("press **option**+**return**") did not work. I tried a bunch of other key combinations, but they didn't work either.

#### What did work for me

I just deleted the **end** at the last line and that allowed me to use the "return" to insert new lines until I added the **end** again.